# What font is used for the intro of The Joy of Painting?

Tags: font-identification

## Exordium

I've tried the sites suggested by [this meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/37568):

- [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
- [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)
- [Serif Font Identification Guide](http://www.bowfinprintworks.com/SerifGuide/serifsearch.php)
- [What Font is](http://whatfontis.com/)

---

This is the intro screen from Bob Ross', *The Joy of Painting*.

[image]
[image]

The show created episodes from 1983 to 1994, which may help identify the font. The intro pictured above, contains:

- a cursive font
- some kind of stencil font
- a serif font

I'm looking for the name of the stencil font (used for "Bob Ross") or a close likeness of it.

---

<sup>Note: Comments regarding the other fonts pictured are *much* appreciated, but not on-topic to this question. Please e-mail me, or message me in one of the chat rooms.</sup>

Comment: Try looking for "art deco" and "art deco caps" in font sites. You should be able to get, if not the exact font, something pretty close

Comment: The closest art deco fonts I could find on any site (dafont.com, fonts.com, Google, etc.) were still much too different from what I'm looking for. @spiral

Comment: I find myself upvoting a font-id question. Exemplary in how it should be done. Thanks, Zach!

Comment: Something like "broadway engraved" is quite close in style: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/broadway/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From that era it's probably not a computer font but a *phototypesetting* typeface. Many have never been vectorized. I looked though an 1965 Photo-Lettering Inc. catalogue and found one with a similar style, unfortunately not really a close match.

The section of the catalogue is called Pop Type, I added the header info for further explanations.

[image]

Comment: plus one for books. Love those old specimen catalogs

Comment: man i'd love to sit down and make some of those into modern fonts. i don't imagine copyrights allow such a thing.

Answer (score -1):

for the script font, "murphy Script" comes close

Comment: Well, please add a screenshot of this font and if you have a link to it please add the link too.  As it stands now noone can proof, if this font comes closes or not.  Where did you see differences?  Please explain better what you mean.  Welcome to GD.SE!