# What are the fonts used in Bob Ross's Intro for the Joy of Painting

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I saw from another post [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/what-font-is-used-for-the-intro-of-the-joy-of-painting) that had the font for his name but didn't have the answers for his signature and the "Joy of Painting" part of the title.

I've used the links from the [meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) but still couldn't really narrow the font down. Since this logo was from back in the mid-1900's, maybe it was never vectorized but I'm still hoping that there is a vectorized form of the font somewhere.

I'm looking for the font for "Bob Ross" and the font for "Joy of Painting". If anyone has any idea what these fonts are, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The subtle formal differences between same characters show that it's not a font but a handwriting logo.

[image: o]

[image: i]

[image: n]

The same in Bob Ross's "o" and "s":

[image]

You can make an advanced search at myfont.com using: `lettering` + `brush` + `calligraphy` + `handwritten` to find some similar fonts

[image: search]